# Setting additional brackets according to the pattern in the operator

Tags: math-operators, auto-completion

Good day everyone!

Maybe someone can suggest how to define a new (or override an existing) operator in a document, so that depending on the argument, the external output changes. In particular, I'm interested in setting additional brackets by pattern.

Let me explain my proposal using the example of an existing operator `\sin{ }`. If the expression to which the operator is applied (argument) has only one character, then it is obvious that no additional brackets are needed to determine the scope of the operator. However, if the expression contains, for example, a sum, product or another mathematical operation, the wrong expression will be displayed without additional brackets. It would be convenient if the use of operators would take care of placing additional brackets as needed.

Thus, in the case I described above, the overridden operator `\sin` must have the following mapping for different arguments.

| Entry form | Default result | What I want in printing result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\sin{x}$ | [image] | [image] |
| $\sin{x + y}$ | [image] | [image] |
| $\sin{\left( x + y \right)}$ | [image] | [image] |
| $\sin{(x + y)}$ | [image] | [image] |
|  |  |  |
| $\sin{x^{2}}$ | [image] | [image] |
| $\sin{x}^2$ | [image] | [image] |
| $\sin^{2}{x}$ | [image] | [image] |

That is, the second through fourth choices should output identical results, without the output of additional single brackets. However, if there were double brackets, such as `\sin{((x))}`, then you should output the double brackets (whatever the author's intention).

Of course, it is possible that what I would like to see may be very difficult to achieve in `LaTeX`, or not achievable at all, but I hope for the best. :-)

Comment: +1 just for the patience to have inserted all the images

Comment: Looks like you need an equation pre-processor which can do AST level manipulations. Maybe math softwares like Mathematica and Sage, and math libraries of (general purpose) programming languages like python and haskell can do such things.

Comment: Good day also to you and ....I approve the comment of @CarLaTeX.